# Swift Charts module with valueFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'm using Charts with Swift, my x axis is an array of months [0,0.5,1.5,...,240] but what I want to show on x-axis is years so my new x axis would be [0.0, 1,2,3...,20];I used

```
lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(23)
```

And now I'm stuck with formatting part I don't know how to format x array to be both integer and for years.

Comment: Show the code you used to draw the chart please.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used to draw the chart, I didn't know how to use:

```
lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter?.stringForXValue(Int, original: String, viewPortHandler: lineChartView.viewPortHandler)
```

I tried to use the override function that has been mentioned in other solutions but it was not calling.

```
   var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]();
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p3Arr,name:"p3",color: UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p5Arr,name:"p5",color: UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p10Arr,name:"p10",color: UIColor.greenColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p25Arr,name:"p25",color: UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p50Arr,name:"p50",color: UIColor.purpleColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p75Arr,name:"p75",color: UIColor.yellowColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p90Arr,name:"p90",color: UIColor.orangeColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p95Arr,name:"p95",color: UIColor.brownColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    dataSets.append(getLineChartData(xArr, y: p97Arr,name:"p97",color: UIColor.cyanColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)))
    //4 - pass our months in for our x-axis label value along with our dataSets
    let data: LineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: xArr, dataSets: dataSets)
    data.setValueTextColor(UIColor.redColor());

    lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(23);

    lineChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false;
    lineChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false;

     //lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter?.stringForXValue(12, original: "", viewPortHandler: lineChartView.viewPortHandler)
    lineChartView.data = data
```